# How do I fade in element only AFTER content fades out jQuery with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

http://amyyatsuk.com/contact.html

I have an HTML form that uses jQuery ajax() to submit to a php processing page.  In the success function of the ajax() call I have the following:

```
success: function() {
    $('#contactForm').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#hidden').delay(.1000).fadeIn(1500); 
    return false;
```

These effects are simultaneous.  I'm looking to fade in the hidden div only after the contact form is fully faded out.

Thanks

Comment: All info you need is in the jQuery API :) http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: Before I knew about async javascript...  hehe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fadeOut and fadeIn effects contain an onComplete callback (optional):

```
$('#contactForm').fadeOut(1000, function(){
  $('#hidden').fadeIn(1500); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a handy built in callback for that :

```
success: function() {
    $('#contactForm').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('#hidden').fadeIn(1500); 
    });
    return false;
```

Comment: Is that `.` before the delay on purpose?

Comment: That was my attempt to delay it 'till after the fade out not realizing it should be a callback function.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second parameter to your fade out that contains the fade in you want to do. E.G

```
success: function() {
$('#contactForm').fadeOut(1000,function(){
$('#hidden').fadeIn(1500);
});
return false;
```

This will only fire once the fadeOut completes. Covered in the API Docs - http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/